# Howto get an INT output from select statement

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$linenumber = Get-Content "C:\temp\test.INI" | select-string -Pattern 'testinput' | select LineNumber
```

Which returns

```
LineNumber
----------
        15
```

But I want to go above that line so I try to do

```
$linenumbernew = $linenumber-1
```

which returns an op_Subtraction:String error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access the `LineNumber` property instead:

```
$linenumbernew = $linenumber.LineNumber - 1
```

Here's a quick example:

```
> $lineNumber = "testinput" | select-string -pattern "testinput" | select LineNumber;

> $lineNumber

LineNumber
----------
         1

> $lineNumber.LineNumber

1

> $lineNumber.LineNumber.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code returns an object with property `LineNumber`. If the pattern is found in more places in the input file, it will return an array of objects with that property.

In your test case, you could do

```
# find the first (or only) line that contains the pattern and convert to int
$linenumber = [int](Get-Content "C:\temp\test.INI" | 
    Select-String -Pattern 'testinput' | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber)[0]

$linenumbernew = $linenumber-1
```

<sup>P.S. By using `-ExpandProperty`, the function will return the *contents* of the property instead of the object holding that property</sup>